# If a LinkedList is empty, return nothing from a method that returns an int?

Tags: java, linked-list, return

EDIT: Solved. Returning a 0 works, apparently!

Ok so long story short, I have to return an int value, but nothing when a Linked List is empty. How do I do it?

```
public int countDuplicates() {

int duplicates = 0;

ListNode current = front;

int num = current.data;
current = current.next;

while(current != null) {
    if(current.data == num) {
        duplicates++;
    } else {
        num = current.data;
    }
    current = current.next;
}
return duplicates;
}
```

When I try this:

```
if(front == null) {
    return ;
}
```

This doesn't work. What can I do?

Comment: I just edited my response to suggest that you return a 0...

Comment: @Karan.. Don't edit the question to say that problem is solved. Rather mark one of the answers that solved your issue as accepted. You can click one of the arrow besides every answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the code as you have it now, you must either return an int, throw an exception, or exit.

> 1. Return an int: You'll have to specify a certain int value as the "fail" value and make sure that it is never the case that this value is hit during "normal" execution.
> 2. Throw an exception: Detailed in another answer - you've already shot it down.
> 3. Exit the program... if it makes sense to do that.

The best option may be to change the code - make the function return an Integer, for example, so the `null` option is there. There are surely other ways to work around it, as well.

Answer (score 5):

You can rather throw an [`IllegalArgumentException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html): -

```
if(front == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("List is empty");
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's an alternative but the online compiler that I'm practicing on doesn't accept exceptions.

Comment: @KaranGoel. In that case, what you can do is, rather than `int` return type, use `Integer` return type, and return `null` on empty list. You have no other way out.

Comment: @KaranGoel.. If you change your return type to `Integer`, then returning `null` would work. Returning 0 might be a problem, if it is a valid return value for other condition.

Answer (score 3):

If your method returns an `int` you must determine an acceptable value to represent "nothing". Such as `0` or if valid results are `>= 0`, use a negative value such as `-1` to indicate "nothing".

Alternatively, modify your method to return an `Integer` object in which case you can return `null`.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible for you to either define a fixed value, such as `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, that would indicate that the list is empty, or change the declaration of your method to `public Integer countDuplicates()`, and return `null` when the list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to (or can't) throw an exception, return some "exceptional value", such as a negative number.  For example, Java has a lot of `indexOf(Object somethingToLookFor)` methods that return a -1 if the item isn't found.

In your example, -1 works as exceptional because there can never be -1 duplicates.

Personally, I would just return 0 for an empty List.  An empty list has 0 duplicates.  But if the spec insists on something exceptional, return -1.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the return value from int to object like this

```
public Object countDuplicates() {
    if(////condition)
        return ///int;
    else 
        return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could return a negative value or change the return type to string and parse the result to int.

Answer (score -1):

```
public boolean isEmpty(){
    if (head == null) return true;
    else return false ;
}
```